# Is it possible to authenticate to Azure Service Management API (i.e. classic) with tokens, not certificates?

Tags: azure

I've spent days trying every possible combination of tricks and code that I can to drive the Azure Service Management API using a token, not a certificate.

It is even possible to do so?

```
{
  "defaultEnv": "dev",
  "envs": {
    "dev": {
      "tenant": "redacted.onmicrosoft.com",
      "clientId": "redacted",
      "clientSecret": "redacted",
      "resource": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
      "endpoint": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I successfully get an access token from Azure AD using the above parameters.

I put the access token into a tiny bit of Python:

```
token = 'redacted'
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
    "x-ms-version": "2015-04-01",
}

url = 'https://management.core.windows.net/{}/services/images?api-version=2015-04-01'.format(subscription_id)
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The final error that I have given up on is:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/REDACTEDSUBSCRIPTIONID/services/images?api-version=2015-04-01
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>ForbiddenError</Code><Message>The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.</Message></Error>
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. Please see this response to understand why you're getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac/35194706#35194706.

Comment: @GauravMantri can I ask is this something you have actually done recently and seen it working or is it theoretical? I tried to authenticate as a user to Azure AD and it said "password expired" and I could find no way to clear the password expiration.  Also the instructions you provide in your link say to make the user a "co-admin" but I searched high and low through both the old and new Azure consoles and could not see where to do that.  Would you mind either actually doing the steps you suggest or confirming it is all possible right now?  thanks!

Comment: Hi Duke, I did it a few months ago when I was helping a friend with exact same problem. Regarding password expiration, can you try logging in into Azure Portal (old) as that user? I'm sure it will provide a UI flow where the user can specify new password. Or you could login as yourself (i.e. an Admin) in Azure Portal, go to the AD in question and create a new password for the user. Then when the user logs in he/she will be prompted to change the password automatically. Regarding Co-Admin, in old portal go to Settings and then Administrators tab. You can add this user as co-admin there. HTH.

Comment: I can't see a settings area in the old console.

Comment: It should be the last item in the left hand side menu bar: http://i.stack.imgur.com/reSdF.png.