# Azure REST 403 error

Tags: c#, rest, azure, certificate, http-status-code-403

I am making API calls to Azure REST to get some information about Azure resources to further on monitor Azure services. I'm trying to make calls in the Postman, using JWT in the header, but some calls throws me errors like this:

- `ForbiddenError`
  The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

I figured out that management.azure.com/subscriptions/... works just fine, but  management.core.windows.net/... don't. Anyone can help me with this problem, please?

According to error, I need to get a certificate, but I don't really know how to do it and what to do it.

I really need to get an answer to this request:

```
management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/monitoring/alertrules
```

Comment: Can you share how you are getting access token? Are you logging in as a user or using client id to get the token?

Comment: I get token using PS script. I guess I'm logging in using client id as I using it in the AcquireToken function.

Comment: Most likely that seems to be the cause. Please read the 1st paragraph here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac/35194706#35194706.