# Azure forbidden exception trying to connect programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have the following code:

```
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX/oauth2/authorize";
var clientId = "YYY-YYYY-YYYYY-YYYYYY";
var appKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
var result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCredential);
var token = result.AccessToken;
var creds = new TokenCloudCredentials("ZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZ-ZZZZZZ", token);
var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(creds);
var data = client.WebSites.Get("eastuswebspace", "some-site", new WebSiteGetParameters());
```

I am getting this error on the `client.WebSites.Get()` call:

> The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the
>   certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription

But I am not using a certificate, I am using `AuthenticationContext`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a site-specific error. Do they really support authentication through the M$'s library? Maybe for another URL? Looking at the raw packets data may shed some light on what exactly is happening.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx shows how OAuth authentication works at network level. If it indeed looks like this and the 3rd party server rejects your token, this means it doesn't support OAuth or you provide incorrect codes or something.

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac/35194706#35194706.

Comment: What is the specific nuget and version that you're using?