# How do I create an AlertsClient from an Azure Active Directory secret?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management-api

I have an ASP.NET app where I'm trying to connect to the Azure Monitoring API, but keep getting the following exception.  I tried to follow a powershell tutorial on how to add a role to my app's service principal (or something), but nothing seemed to work, and I'm not sure if I even need to do it:

> ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify
>   that the certificate is valid and is associated with this
>   subscription.

**Code:**

```
var cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);

var context = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(string.Format(
                login,
                tenantId));

var task = context
                .AcquireTokenAsync(apiEndpoint, cred);

task.Wait();

var result = task.Result;

var subCreds = new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, result.AccessToken);  //good AccessToken at this point

var alertsClient = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.AlertsClient(subCreds);

var t = c.Incidents.ListActiveForSubscriptionAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
t.Wait();  //exception at this point
```

Comment: Please see this thread for more information on why you're receiving this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac.

Comment: @GauravMantri that worked perfectly.  Having spent so long on this trying to get the official azure nuget package to work, I have such mixed emotions right now