# How to get Azure Storage Account Key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-active-directory, azure-storage-account

I want to upload a file to an Azure Storage account that is automatically generated (As part of a Service Fabric resource group, with a known name), using C#.

I need to upload the file as a blob to allow it to be publicly available.

The tutorial [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#upload-blob) uses a connection string stored in the App.config file.
Since I want to use the to-be-generated storage account, I can't use such a method.

The prefered method is using the user's AD somehow in order to get the key of the storage account.

This link: [Get Storage Account Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460785.aspx) shows how to GET it with a Rest request, so I guess there is a way to do it using C# code.

It seems to me, that the solution is using the StorageManagementClient [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.storagemanagementclient.aspx), which has a StorageAccounts property, though I could not find a way to authenticate it using AzureAd.

I tried using [AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt473620.aspx), and aquiring a token for diffenent resources, for instance: `https://management.azure.com/`, but when using the token, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException: AuthenticationFailed: The JWT token does not contain expected audience uri 'https://management.core.windows.net/'.
```

When using the resource `https://management.core.windows.net/` I get a different error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
```

Is there a different resource I should use, different method, or maybe it's impossible?

Comment: Please share the code you're using. Also share if you are logging in as yourself to acquire the token. Lastly, for your 2nd error please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac/35194706#35194706. HTH.

Comment: @Bobcat100 Have fixed this issue? If you still have problem about it please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the [Storage Service Management REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.storagemanagementclient.aspx), we need to specify the resource to `https://management.core.windows.net/` instead of `https://management.azure.com/`.  And this is using the operate the classic storage account.

The `https://management.azure.com/` is the new endpoint for the [Azure REST service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/index). If you want to handle the new storage account, you need to use this resource. And below is a sample using the new Azure REST for your reference:

```
POST: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resrouceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageAccountName}/listKeys?api-version=2016-01-01
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```