# Error when using AD to work with Azure Management API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management-api

I'm using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory packages trying to work with Azure Management API from C# code, but when I try to retrieve some data from it, I'm always getting the error:

```
ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
```

There's the code sample I'm using:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management;

var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/mytenant");
var cc = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential("azure-app-id", "azure-app-secret");
var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", cc);

var tokenCred = new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(token.AccessToken);
var client = new ManagementClient(tokenCred);
// this is where I get the error:
var subscriptions = await client.Subscriptions.GetAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're getting this error is because the `Service Principal` (or in other words the Azure AD application) does not have permission on your Azure Subscription. You would need to assign a role to this Service Principal.

Please see this link regarding how you can assign a role in an Azure Subscription to a Service Principal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role.

Once you do that, the error should go away.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant, but I added my application as Owner to IAM on a Subscription level and I'm still getting this error.  

BTW, can I use the Azure Management API only knowing the username & password used to log into the portal? Without needing to create a separate app for this

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access `Classic Resources` using `Service Management API` using the code above. Please check this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue too. And to list the subscription, we need to use the `SubscriptionClient` instead of `ManagementClient`. Here is the code which works well for me:

```
var token = "";
var tokenCred = new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(token);

var subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(tokenCred);
foreach (var subscription in subscriptionClient.Subscriptions.List())
{
    Console.WriteLine(subscription.SubscriptionName);
}
```

**Note**:To make the code work, we need to acquire token using the owner of the subscription instead of the certificate.