# Permissions for Azure database management

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, azure-management

I'm working on a small application to connect to Microsoft Azure, list all databases belonging to a certain resource group, and export all said databases. I'm using the [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.sql.aspx) library for this.

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role), I've managed to set up an app registration in AD for my application and assign it the `Owner` role (for testing), authenticate with Azure and get an access token.

However, when I try to use that token to perform any operations on the database (such as listing all databases, using [IServerOperations.List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.sql.serveroperationsextensions.list.aspx)), I get the following exception:

```
ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
```

The tenant ID, subscription ID, client ID and client secret are all correct, and changing any of them results in a different exception, already at the authentication stage.

How can I fix this? If the correct answer is "switch to [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql?view=azure-dotnet)" I'm perfectly fine with that, but if possible I'd at least like to understand *why* this is happening.

Comment: You need to remove or clear the Azure account first, get authenticated by adding the new Azure Account por the tenant, after that you select a subscription Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HIf the correct answer is "switch to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql" I'm perfectly fine with that, but if possible I'd at least like to understand why this is happening.

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql` implements the **ASM** API(Azure old API).

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to authenticate/authorize an Azure Resource Manager (ASM) API  with **application** permission. 
But Service Management API is a delegated permission and not an application permission.

For more detail information about how to authenticate for **ASM** and **ARM** Rest API, please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190866/error-making-azure-management-library-api-call-when-authenticating-with-azure-ac/35194706#35194706).

> How can I fix this?

`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` implements the ARM API. As you mentioned that you could use the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` to instand of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql`

or you could use **X509 Certificate** based authorization to authorize your ASM API requests. 
For more information about how to authenticate using a management certificate, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert).

**Note**: It is recommanded that to use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` to instead of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql`

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! Switching over to the `Microsoft.Azure` API indeed solved the problem, and thanks to this answer we now know why it did. :)